# Flutter/Dart: Convert String to Color?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, colors

My database has colors saved as a String like `"black"` and so I'm basically looking for a function like this: `Color.FromName("black")`
How can I convert to Color in this situation?

Comment: I have no experience with it, but it seems that [package:color](https://pub.dev/packages/color) might do what you want.  Otherwise it shouldn't be too hard to write a script to scan through Flutter's [`colors.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b8abb4724/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart#L194) and to generate code that maps `String`s to `Color`s.

Comment: expanding on @jamesdlin's comment, package:color has the rgb methods that will match your requirement.

`RgbColor black = new RgbColor.name('black');`

Make sure your DB has the proper CSS color names.
https://www.rapidtables.com/web/css/css-color.html

Comment: maybe you can just create an extension on color class and put all colors from db to extension?

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes I will write a script to generate code that maps Strings to Colors.

Comment: @thusith.92 I tried to do this : `RgbColor black = new RgbColor.name('black');` but it's not working because  the packages Painting.dart and Color.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I wrote a code that maps Strings to Colors

```
Map<String,Color>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
I ran it for hexadecimal colors.  

{    
    Category category = categoryList[index];
    String hexString = category.color; // string value e.g: 'EF9A9A' from database 
     int myColor = int.parse("0xff$hexString");
     return Card(
     ...
     color: Color(myColor),
}

class Category {
    String id;
    String title;
    String color;

    Category({
        this.id,
        this.title,
        this.color,
    });

  
    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        id: json["id"] ,
        title: json["title"],
        color: json["color"],
    );
}
```